# Xcodeの下限の iOS サポートバージョン

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

Xcode13にバージョンをあげてみましたが、サポートできる　Xcodeのバージョンごとにdeployment targetは下限どこまででしょうか。
あまり考えてなかったのですが、私の作ったアプリはdeployment target ios9としてます。ios9の端末がもう一般に使われてないことは知ってますが、「deployment target」を理由なくあげるのもなんなんでそのままにしてました。
１３にあげたことで、下限のバージョンをあげた方がいいか迷ってます。個人アプリなので警告などは出てもあまり気になりません。

Comment: [Xcode 13 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes)の`Overview`にはDeploymentではないですが`The Xcode 13 release supports on-device debugging for iOS 9 and later,...`と書いてあるようですが。

Comment: サポートできる下限のOSバージョンがiOS9より上になったら、ビルドが警告ではなくエラーで通らなくなると思います。なので、ビルドできる限りはそのままでも良いような気がします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Xcode13ってまだios9サポートしてるのですね。どこまで下限設けるかって悩みます。今回はそのままにしたいと思います。